# SimplePie Problem

Tags: php, xml, rss, feed, simplepie

I got problem with SimplePie while retrieving mostly feeds.

- At first, at says to use force_feed()
- But when i enabled force_feed(), it says again:

  > This XML document is invalid, likely due to invalid characters. XML error: EntityRef: expecting ';' at line ... etc

Sample [Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=php&sort=newest)

**It is OK on SimplePie Official Demo Page** [here](http://simplepie.org/demo)
**I want like that.**

p.s. I also have installed all required libraries and are working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the stackoverflow feed is not working due to the nature of the content (contains code).

I have had similar issues with seemingly "normal" feeds using many feed parsers, though the one I've had the most luck with recently is Zend_Feed.  Give it a try from [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.html)

Comment: If stackoverflow feed is not working one, why it is working over http://simplepie.org/demo page?

I want like that on my side.